# Extracting data from JSON field in Redshift

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract some data from a JSON field.

```
[{"id": 10001, "person1": {"name": "Kevin", "role": "junior"},
               "person2": {"name": "Scott", "role": "senior"}}]
```

I am trying to extract the name and role under each ID.

I tried the below but it returned empty record.

```
SELECT json_extract_path(column_name::json,'person1','name') FROM table
```

Comment: Does the field contain the exact text that you have shown above (including the square brackets)? Have you considered loading this data into a table as normal columns, rather than keeping it as JSON? It would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you have shown is:

- A list (as indicated by `[]`)
- That contains a dictionary
- That contains a dictionary

You will first need to extract the first list element, then use the command you have supplied.

Try something like:

```
SELECT 
  json_extract_path(
    json_extract_array_element_text(column_name::json, 0),
    'person1',
    'name'
  ) 
FROM table
```

Comment: thank you. I was able to get the required info using the below :

` select json_extract_path(
    jsonb_extract_array_element_text(column_name)::json,
    'person1',
    'name'`